# Xamarin WebView: Cannot login using Facebook and Google account

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, xamarin

I cannot login using facebook login button and google login button in the webview. They will popup their login page.

The problem with Xamarin WebView:

1. Facebook - After login, it will redirect me to blank page, instead of coming back to the previous page.
2. Google - Google redirects me to their policy page saying I should not use the embedded webview, instead I have to use my device browser (Chrome, etc...).

I am a website developer so I am new on this case. I need to use Webview because I have deadlines.

Is there a way to make the login button from the html to redirects me to the device browser to login? Or is there another way to solve this?

This is the button generated from Facebook:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

and this is from google:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="light" data-width="300" data-height="50" data-longtitle="true">button</div>
```

---

### EDITED

So after I change the user agent, I am able to go into the google login page. Then after I login, it gives me blank screen.

How to fix this?

This is how my code receive the callback after a successful login:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    $('#frm_externalLogin').find('#Provider').val('Google');
    $('#frm_externalLogin').find('#ProviderDisplayName').val( profile.getName());
    $('#frm_externalLogin').find('#ProviderUserId').val(profile.getId());
    $('#frm_externalLogin').find('#Email').val(profile.getEmail());

    $('#frm_externalLogin').submit();
}

function FBLogin() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function (response) {
        $('#frm_externalLogin').find('#Provider').val('Facebook');
        $('#frm_externalLogin').find('#ProviderDisplayName').val( response.name);
        $('#frm_externalLogin').find('#ProviderUserId').val(response.id);
        $('#frm_externalLogin').find('#Email').val(response.email);

        $('#frm_externalLogin').submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: `it will redirect me to blank page` no, it will redirect you to the `redirect URL` that you entered in your development console. `Google redirects me to their policy page` use any custom user agent header

Comment: I used custom user agent and I can finally go into google login page, but after I login from it, blank screen shows in my webview. In my website, any successful login will be caught by the javascript and then redirect it to the authorization page. Somehow the webview cannot mimic the same workflow.